# Spring Boot Injecting Implementations for Prod and Test

Tags: spring-boot

I'm new to spring boot and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to make dependency injection work for deployment and testing.

I have a @RestController and a supporting @Service. The service injects another class that is an interface for talking to Kafka. For the Kafka interface I have two implementations: one real and one fake. The real one I want to use in production and the fake in test.

My approach is to use two different configuration for each environment (prod and test).

```
@Configuration
public class AppTestConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public KafkaMessagePublisher kafkaMessagePublisher() {
    return new KafkaMessagePublisherFakeImpl();
  }
}

@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public KafkaMessagePublisher kafkaMessagePublisher() {
    return new KafkaMessagePublisherImpl();
  }
}
```

Then in my main application I would like to somehow load AppConfiguration.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DeployerServiceApiApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DeployerServiceApiApplication.class, args);
  }

  // TODO: somehow load here...
}
```

And in my test load the fake configuration somehow

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class DeployerServiceApiApplicationTest {

  @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;

  // TODO: somehow load AppTestConfiguration here


  @Test
  public void testDeployAction() throws Exception {
    ...
    ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc.perform(...);
    ...
  }
}
```

I've spent the better part of a day trying to figure this out. What I'm trying to accomplish here is fundamental and should be straight forward yet I keep running into issues which makes me wonder if the way I'm thinking about this is all wrong.

Comment: I was never a fan of "mock" since it does not really replicate your production. I usually create a temp database or temp kafka (like docker or k8s) then set your environment variables or using spring profile. Once the test is done, you can trash that test kafka. This way you are sure that your code works

Comment: by "test" environment do you mean junit test case?

Comment: yes junit test environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure if i understand your question completely but from description i guess you wish to initialize bean based on environment. Please see below.

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class AppTestConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public KafkaMessagePublisher kafkaMessagePublisher() {
    return new KafkaMessagePublisherFakeImpl();
  }
}

@Profile("prod")
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public KafkaMessagePublisher kafkaMessagePublisher() {
    return new KafkaMessagePublisherImpl();
  }
```

and then you can pass the "`-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`" argument while starting you application using java command or you can also specify the profile in your test case like below.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfile("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class DeployerServiceApiApplicationTest
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spring profiles, you can annotate your test class with `@ActiveProfiles("test-kafka")` and your test configuration with `@Profile("test-kafka")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy task in spring boot world

Rewrite your classes as follows:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class AppTestConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public KafkaMessagePublisher kafkaMessagePublisher() {
    return new KafkaMessagePublisherFakeImpl();
  }
}

@Profile("prod")
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public KafkaMessagePublisher kafkaMessagePublisher() {
    return new KafkaMessagePublisherImpl();
  }
}
```

This will instruct spring boot to load the relevant configuration when the "prod"/"test" specified.

Then you can start your application in production with `--spring.profiles.active=prod` and in the Test you can write something like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DeployerServiceApiApplicationTest {
...
}
```

If you want to run all the tests with this profile and do not want to write this `ActiveProfiles` annotation you can create `src/test/resources/application.properties` and put into it: `spring.active.profiles=test`